Broken pipe when re-entering a tmux session running a python multiprocessing script
I have a long running python script that I need to execute on a server in my university lab. Instead of executing in directly in the SSH client and risking the connection to go down and thus the process to be killed, I first start a tmux session:
tmux new -s preprocessing

and run my script in the session:
python3 path/to/my/scirpt.py

After that, I exit the session and close the ssh connection.
After a while, I want to check the progress, so I re-connect via SSH to the server and attach to the tmux session:
tmux attach -t preprocessing

I firstly see in the terminal the progress of the script - it has a progress bar like this:
Processing 1st Step:   7%|███▌                                                 | 61725/921600 [11:11:49<155:59:00,  1.53it/s]

But after some seconds I get this error:
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "/home/plodir2/network-predictive-analysis/scripts/data_preprocessing_MILC+LAMMPS+UR_lammps_1056.py", line 419, in process_chunk
    if (application_iteration, router_id) not in list(processed_routers):
  File "<string>", line 2, in __len__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 817, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plodir2/network-predictive-analysis/scripts/data_preprocessing_MILC+LAMMPS+UR_lammps_1056.py", line 600, in <module>
    pool.starmap(process_chunk, [(application_chunk, data_to_add_list, processed_routers, inactive_nodes_lists_processed_iterations) for application_chunk in application_chunks])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 375, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I think this is related to the tmux session, because I get it right after attaching to it. Additionally, the 11 hours shown on the progress bar precisely matches the time that has passed since I started the script and when I checked its progress. Furthermore, I have run the script with a smaller data set and it processed it with no errors (ran it in SSH while keeping connection alive).
I can provide more details about the script, but it is essentally intended to process a pandas dataframe, application_data by splitting it into chunks, each of which is handled by a different process. This was done to improve performance given the big amount of data.
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_processes = 400
    application_chunks = np.array_split(application_data, num_processes)


    with Manager() as manager:
        data_to_add_list = manager.list()
        processed_routers = manager.list()
        inactive_nodes_lists_processed_iterations = manager.list()
        
        progress_counter = Value('i', 0)
        lock = Lock()

        with tqdm(total=len(application_data), desc="Processing 1st Step") as pbar:
            progress_thread = Thread(target=update_progress_bar, args=(len(application_data), pbar))
            progress_thread.start()

            with Pool(num_processes, initializer=init, initargs=(lock, progress_counter)) as pool:
                pool.starmap(process_chunk, [(application_chunk, data_to_add_list, processed_routers, inactive_nodes_lists_processed_iterations) for application_chunk in application_chunks])

            progress_thread.join()
...

The processes share the processed_routers list, which is read and written in the following way:
def process_chunk(chunk, data_to_add_list, processed_routers, inactive_nodes_lists_processed_iterations):

    for application_data_record in chunk.itertuples():
        application_iteration = application_data_record.iteration # integer value
        router_id = int(application_data_record.node // 4)
        ...

        add_router_data_ports = False
        with lock:
            if (application_iteration, router_id) not in list(processed_routers):
                # keep track of the fact that port 0-10 data has been processed for this iteration for this router
                processed_routers.append((application_iteration, router_id))
                add_router_data_ports = True

        if add_router_data_ports:
            # do stuff
...

basically the list holds tuples (x,y) of integers: the intended behavior is to avoid two processes working on data related to the same tuple.

This might not be the cause, but  a process Poll with 400  workers seems quite unhandly, and unpractical.
Actually, in this model each of the 400 workers will receive the TMUX pseudo-tty files as their stdin/stdout/stderr - and it is most likely that some edge case scenario inside tmux when reconnecting these 1200 files when you reattach  a session that will yield this error.
So, things I'd try there:

create the subprocesses in a way that they have a private, owned by the root process, stdin/stdout/stderr files - instead of sharing the root PTY. - if you can do that, by correctly following the specs on Python's multiprocessing and subprocess docs, the problem should be gone in a deterministic way.

use a more reasonable number of workers in the Pool - keep in mind that in a subprocess Pool, workers are re-used, and it doesn't make much sense to have much more workers the the physical count of available CPU cores there. If your process still leave a lot of unused CPU resources, due to waiting for I/O, for example, something in your architecture have to change to optimize that without requiring 400 workers to max out your physical cores - possibly using ASYNCIO, either on the host or on the workers. Diminishing the number of workers is ikely fixing your error, but not in a deterministic way. I'd advise doing it along with the fix suggested in item (1) anyway.



I have implemented item (1) and waiting to check results. My process is not I/O bound, but the reason I use such an high number of workers is that the df is very big - ~50M rows - and each process perform many chunk.loc operations (ie queries on the chunk), so I thought performing queries on a smaller amount of data could have been beneficial, even at the cost of higher overhead for ctx switches, but this reasoning may be wrong. Thanks for the suggestions

yes - you are mistaking the data partitions with the number of workers. Workers would be reused  - that is the WHOLE idea of using a multiprocessing Pool and the .map calls. - just use two different numbers, one for data partitions (~400) , and another for the number or workers (your number of physical CPU cores + 10-20%)
